# What should be the correct preposition in this sentence? In, To, or Of?

Tags: prepositions

"There are some disadvantages ***in/of/to*** using the Internet"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Books Ngram viewer shows that all three prepositions are commonly used after disadvantage/s. Although the popularity of each has risen and fallen over the years, **disadvantage of** is currently the leader by a wide margin.

In your example I would opt for **some disadvantages to using** although either of the other two might also work.

https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disadvantage+to%2Cdisadvantage+in%2Cdisadvantage+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2008